# Time Zone Synchronization

Tags: java, python, synchronization, timezone

I have a server which runs on Java and client which runs on python. When I connect the client and server I have to sync the time from server to client.
I was successful in connecting and sending streams from server to client. I wanted to know what is the usual way to send time and timezone. How can i do it? For now i am sending time in miliseconds and paring that in python to get the date and time. But I don't know how to send time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should transmit and process the time in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and not mess with timezones at all. In Java, this is exactly what `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns.

**Edit**: The correct format to transfer timezone information is to use a continent/city ID as in the [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), e.g. "America/New_York" or "Europe/Berlin". This is also used by Java. The base timezone offset is insufficient because it cannot accomodate daylight savings time and historical timezone changes.

Comment: Thanks Michael Borgwardt, The main issue is like my device is not a PC it a device. The first time it boots it connects with the server and it should sync time and timezone with the server.

Comment: @skalluraya: see extended answer

Comment: Thanks Michael Borgwardt, Will try this and let you know

Answer (score 3):

Do you know NTP, the [Network Time Protocol](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)?

Comment: Thanks Tichodroma fro the quick reply, I didnt knew about NTP. The link provides good info. But I dont know whether python client will have NTP support. Its not a PC. so wanted to know if i can send some sting or integer and sync both time and timezone.